# SQL query group where one column is missing specific data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL database that consists of order book information, e.g.

| ORDER_ID | TIMESTAMP | OPERATION | ORDER_STATUS | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:00:01 | INSERT | New | ... |
| 1 | 00:00:05 | UPDATE | Partially Filled | ... |
| 2 | 00:00:07 | UPDATE | Partially Filled | ... |
| 1 | 00:00:08 | CANCEL | Filled | ... |
| 3 | 00:00:08 | INSERT | NEW | ... |

Now, this data is not always perfectly filled, as in, sometimes there will be order_ids with missing information.

One such problem I'm trying to identify are orders (so, all orders with the same order_ID) that are missing the Operation 'INSERT', e.g. there are order_ids that have the operation 'UPDATE' or 'CANCEL', but not an 'INSERT'. In the example table above, that would be the case for order_id 2 (it has an 'UPDATE', but no 'INSERT')

I was able to perform this analysis by just download the whole data set and analyzing the data with Python, but I'd like to be able to do this (faster) with a direct SQL query, if possible.

Comment: use `where not exists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation to check if some status exists along with others.

```
select order_id
from sample
where operation in ('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'CANCEL', 'OTHER_STATUS_TO_CHECK_TOGETHER_WITH_INSERT')
group by order_id
having count(case operation when 'INSERT' then 1 end) = 0
```

For your sample data it returns

| ORDER_ID |
| --- |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vvVwgPO3)

Comment: Nice, this seems to be by far the fastest query from all the options (as in, takes only a few seconds whereas the others take minutes).

Comment: @Olorun You are welcome! This solution scans the table only once, and doesn't require sorting (generally Oracle performs `hash group by`) because it doesn't answer any questions about event order, so this is quite fast operation.

Comment: Actually after double-checking, I don't think this solution returns what I wanted. It returned a list of order ids, but when I did a double-check for those order IDs, it looked like they actually had the 'INSERT' operation. (At least it did with my modifications, I basically just added a simple "AND as_of_date > to_date('13.1.23', 'DD.MM.YY')" to the WHERE part.)

Comment: @Olorun So please provide sample data to reproduce the issue, because as of your current dataset in the question it returns what you've requested

Comment: Ah, it was my fault. The example/sample is trivial - an order id can take place over several days. So if you imagine my cutoff (AS_OF_DATE) is the 13th, but some order ids have an insert on the 12th as well as update/cancels on the 13th, they will show up as missing insert

Comment: @Olorun This was my assumption, but to resolve the issue you may use some known offset for preliminary filtering (it may be of several month wide just to apply some restrictions) and then add `having ... and min(as_of_date) > date '2023-01-13'` to get all the ID's that have status changes after your date

Comment: Now I just got rid of the date filtering altogether. Since your query is so fast, even for the whole database it only took about 2 minutes to find all of those orders, around 150,000. I know this should probably warrant it's only question, but is there some fast way to download all order data for those 150,000 identified order ids?

Comment: @Olorun I cannot tell. I personally use `export` feature of IDE.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following helps:

```
Select Order_Id
from t
where Operation in ('UPDATE','CANCEL')
and not exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t2.Order_Id = t.Order_Id and t2.Operation = 'INSERT'
);
```

Comment: It seems to be working, at least the query is running. Think I'll have to add some more specifiers since the database is massive, and the query might take a long time to finish.

Comment: If you just want to find orders with missing `insert` rows without requiring either the other two you could remove the `in ('UPDATE','CANCEL')`

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching to determine whether there is an `INSERT` operation before an `UPDATE` or `CANCEL` operation:

```sql
SELECT order_id
FROM   order_book
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY order_id
  ORDER     BY timestamp
  MEASURES
    COUNT(insert_op.operation) AS has_insert
  PATTERN ( insert_op? (update_op|cancel_op)+ )
  DEFINE
    insert_op AS operation = 'INSERT',
    update_op AS operation = 'UPDATE',
    cancel_op AS operation = 'CANCEL'
)
WHERE has_insert = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE order_book (ORDER_ID, TIMESTAMP, OPERATION, ORDER_STATUS ) AS
SELECT 1, '00:00:01', 'INSERT', 'New'              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '00:00:05', 'UPDATE', 'Partially Filled' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '00:00:07', 'UPDATE', 'Partially Filled' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '00:00:08', 'CANCEL', 'Filled'           FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '00:00:08', 'INSERT', 'NEW'              FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER_ID |
| --- |
| 2 |

---

Or, if you want groups where an `UPDATE` or `CANCEL` operation is first in the group then you can use:

```sql
SELECT order_id
FROM   order_book
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY order_id
  ORDER     BY timestamp
  PATTERN ( ^ (update_op|cancel_op) )
  DEFINE
    update_op AS operation = 'UPDATE',
    cancel_op AS operation = 'CANCEL'
);
```

Which outputs the same.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZN8Rch-5)

Comment: Quite nice. And I like your thinking for the second idea as that is another business problem I'll have to analyze ("show me all the orders for which INSERT is not first").

Comment: I'm not sure how performance is measured for SQL, but is there some easy way to compare the speed (as in, how long the query took to return the items) for these different answers posted?

Comment: @Olorun For your first comment, you could use `PATTERN ( ^ not_insert ) DEFINE not_insert AS operation != 'INSERT'` (rather than listing all the non-insert patterns)

Comment: For your second comment, you can look at the explain plans for the queries and check if one plan is better than the other (but interpreting explain plans is not straight forward) or you run all the queries several/many times and time the response and then you can benchmark it for your hardware/tables/data/network/etc.

Comment: And I'm having a bit of a problem extending your solution. Since the database contains info from several years, it would make sense to reduce the scope to use another field such as TIMESTAMP or AS_OF_DATE (not included in my example), e.g., only for data after the 10th of January. With the other answers it was a simple WHERE has_insert = 0 AND as_of_date > to_date('10.1.23', 'DD.MM.YY').

Comment: @Olorun If I have what you want to do correct, you need to perform any filtering in a sub-query in the `FROM` clause (or use a sub-query factoring clause/CTE to do the filtering) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q0dJgc0W) so that it happens before the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` is applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251203/discussion-between-olorun-and-mt0).